# Cannot finde symbol error, null pointer

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, symbols

There are not compiling errors now, the value wont show, only the message "number:"
I've already been here, for the exception that before it shown "number:NULL" but i think i am getting there... thanks to all of you. I've been reading threads for about a week, but i learned more tonight  with you advises

Login class

```
public class Login_JPanel extends JPanel
{
    JLabel welcomeMessage,
    mainPicture;

    JButton playerregistrationJB = new JButton ( "Player Registration" );   

    JLabel userAccountNumberJLabel  = new JLabel("<HTML><CENTER><FONT SIZE=6 
    COLOR=YELLOW>Please, enter your account number below and then click on player
    registration to continue </COLOR></CENTER></HTML>");

    JTextField useraccountnumberJTF  = new JTextField();

    public Login_JPanel()
    {   
        //========================================================
        //SET UP USERNAME JLABEL AND TEXT FIELD
        //========================================================
        add(userAccountNumberJLabel);
        userAccountNumberJLabel.setBounds( 322, 335, 300, 155 );

        add(useraccountnumberJTF);
        useraccountnumberJTF.setBounds (330, 500,  90, 25 ); 

        playerregistrationJB.setBounds( 350, 600, 325, 75 );
        playerregistrationJB.setFont( new Font( "Broadway", Font.BOLD, 30 ) );
        playerregistrationJB.setForeground( Color.red );
        playerregistrationJB.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
        add( playerregistrationJB);         

        add( welcomeMessage = new JLabel( "Welcome!!" ) );
        welcomeMessage.setBounds(0,0,50,23);

        add( mainPicture = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("henkidama.jpg") ) );
        mainPicture.setBounds(0,0,50,50);

        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(0,0,1000,800);    
    }   
}
```

This is the playerregistration panel

```
public class PlayerRegistration_JPanel extends JPanel
{

    Login_JPanel loginJP = new Login_JPanel();

    JLabel welcomeMessage,
    mainPicture;

    JLabel useraccountnumberJL = new JLabel();

    JButton submitJB = new JButton ( "Submit" );    

    public PlayerRegistration_JPanel()
    {
        add(useraccountnumberJL);
        useraccountnumberJL.setText("number: " +  
                       loginJP.useraccountnumberJTF.getText());    
        useraccountnumberJL.setBounds( 100, 75, 625, 200 );
        useraccountnumberJL.setFont( new Font( "Broadway", Font.BOLD, 18 ) );

        submitJB.setBounds( 350, 600, 325, 75 );
        submitJB.setFont( new Font( "Broadway", Font.BOLD, 30 ) );
        submitJB.setForeground( Color.red );
        submitJB.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
        add( submitJB); 

        add( welcomeMessage = new JLabel( "Welcome to Building Another Panel!!" ) );
        welcomeMessage.setBounds(0,0,50,23);

        add( mainPicture = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("henkidama.jpg") ) );
        mainPicture.setBounds(0,0,50,50);

        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(0,0,1000,800);        
    }   
}
```

There is a `JLabel` asking the user to input a number, up to this point a `String`, then user is supposed to click the `playerregistrationJB`, and the number appearing in the `PlayerRegistration_JPanel`.
Also, there is a `ProccessedJPanel` where i call all my buttons by `ActionListener`, 
also a `finalJpanel` where i have my main in one frame. I don't know where is the problem since my `JTextField` is global (though we don't have any such thing like GLOBAL VARIABLE in Java).

Comment: Do watch the edits and do point me, If I am wrong somewhere !! Moreover, where exactly had you initialized your `Login_JPanel` Class's Object inside your `PlayerRegistration_JPanel` to access `useraccountnumberJTF.getText()`, something like `Login_JPanel loginPanel = new Login_JPanel(); loginPanel.useraccountnumberJTF.getText();` ?

Comment: Simply inside your `Login_JPanel` class, declare `JTextField` like this `public static JTextField useraccountnumberJTF  = new JTextField();` now inside your `PlayerRegistration_JPanel` Class access it like this `Login_JPanel.useraccountnumberJTF.getText()`. That will do :-)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't declare `useraccountnumberJTF` in the class `PlayerRegistration_JPanel` (it's declared only in `Login_JPanel` class) yet you call it in this line. This is your error.

Comment: i have tried declaring it for example in my playerregistration jpanel to write this: JTextField useraccountnumberJTF;
 but then i get the null pointer Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PlayerRegistration_JPanel.<init>(PlayerRegistration_JPanel.java:38) in the same line

Comment: @Grecia Of course, then you still have to initialize it. To have the functionality you want, you should make sure your code can access that particular field that is used in your UI, as I explained in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Where is your `useraccountnumberJTF`. You have declare it in another class. In order to acces the other class property, you must create oject of other class in your class and then access the other class property. Also both the class must be in same package.

```
public class PlayerRegistration_JPanel extends JPanel
{
     Login_JPanel login = new Login_JPanel();
     public PlayerRegistration_JPanel() 
     {
          add(useraccountnumberJL);
          useraccountnumberJL.setText(login.useraccountnumberJTF.getText());
          useraccountnumberJL.setBounds( 100, 75, 625, 200 );
          useraccountnumberJL.setFont( new Font( "Broadway", Font.BOLD, 18 ) );
      }
}
```

Comment: it's not giving me any error now, the Jbutton works 'cause the next PlayerRegistration_JPane is shown, i can see the picture but there is no JLabel showing the number ... thanks for your help

Comment: Did you get any data from textfield? I mean get text from textfield and tyr to display it on console.. It may be good practicing of debugging..

Answer (score 2):

Your `JTextField useraccountnumberJTF` is not global. It is a member variable of your `Login_JPanel` class. This means there is one such text field for each instance of your `Login_JPanel` class. How should you `PlayerRegistration_JPanel` know to which field you are referring ?

If you want access to that field, pass an instance of `Login_JPanel` in the constructor of `PlayerRegistration_JPanel` and ask that instance for its field.

This is a rather basic OO concept. Perhaps it is good to re-read some tutorials, like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for example

Answer (score 2):

Why you think that you can directly use `useraccountnumberJTF` in second class?

You are mixing variables of 2 classes. You can not use variable defined in one class directly in second class without reference to first class. You dont have `useraccountnumberJTF` in second class so it gives error in that class. What you can do is find a way to pass this variables value to second class.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `useraccountnumberJTF`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Login_JPanel extends JPanel {
    JLabel welcomeMessage, mainPicture;

    JButton playerregistrationJB = new JButton("Player Registration");
    JLabel userAccountNumberJLabel = new JLabel("<HTML><CENTER><FONT SIZE=6 COLOR=YELLOW>Please, enter your account number below and then click on playerregistration to continue </COLOR></CENTER></HTML>");
    JTextField useraccountnumberJTF = new JTextField();

    public Login_JPanel() {
        // ========================================================
        // SET UP USERNAME JLABEL AND TEXT FIELD
        // ========================================================
        add(userAccountNumberJLabel);
        userAccountNumberJLabel.setBounds(322, 335, 300, 155);

        add(useraccountnumberJTF);
        useraccountnumberJTF.setBounds(330, 500, 90, 25);

        playerregistrationJB.setBounds(350, 600, 325, 75);
        playerregistrationJB.setFont(new Font("Broadway", Font.BOLD, 30));
        playerregistrationJB.setForeground(Color.red);
        playerregistrationJB.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(playerregistrationJB);

        add(welcomeMessage = new JLabel("Welcome!!"));
        welcomeMessage.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 23);

        add(mainPicture = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("henkidama.jpg")));
        mainPicture.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);

        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 800);
    }

    public String getUseraccountnumberJTFText() {
        return useraccountnumberJTF.getText();
    }
}
```

PlayerRegistration_JPanel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlayerRegistration_JPanel extends JPanel
{
    JLabel welcomeMessage,
           mainPicture;
    JLabel useraccountnumberJL = new JLabel();
    JButton submitJB = new JButton ( "Submit" );    

    public PlayerRegistration_JPanel(Login_JPanel panel)
    {
        add(useraccountnumberJL);
        useraccountnumberJL.setText(panel.getUseraccountnumberJTFText());
        useraccountnumberJL.setBounds( 100, 75, 625, 200 );
        useraccountnumberJL.setFont( new Font( "Broadway", Font.BOLD, 18 ) );

        submitJB.setBounds( 350, 600, 325, 75 );
        submitJB.setFont( new Font( "Broadway", Font.BOLD, 30 ) );
        submitJB.setForeground( Color.red );
        submitJB.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
        add( submitJB); 

        add( welcomeMessage = new JLabel( "Welcome to Building Another Panel!!" ) );
        welcomeMessage.setBounds(0,0,50,23);

        add( mainPicture = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("henkidama.jpg") ) );
        mainPicture.setBounds(0,0,50,50);

        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(0,0,1000,800);
    }   
}
```

And please read this: http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

EDIT:

The declaration of the Classes should be so:

```
private Login_JPanel loginPanel;

private void theMethodWhoDeclareLoginJPanel() {
    loginPanel = new Login_JPanel();
}

private void theMethodWhoDeclarePlayerRegistrationJPanel() {
    new PlayerRegistration_JPanel(loginPanel);
}
```

Comment: i tried doing this, i get this error. PlayerRegistration_JPanel.java:37: error: non-static method getUseraccountnumberJTFText() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: soo... `PlayerRegistration_JPanel` is static?

Comment: no >_> supposedly that's the point of this program, it is a program with non-static methods... :/ JGrasp it's a pain in the ass

Comment: i did this again, now i dont have any errors but the number wont show.. i had to initialize it like this  PlayerRegistration_JPanel PlayerRegistrationJP = new PlayerRegistration_JPanel (LoginJP );
 for the program to wun, but i stll cant get the value

Comment: When do you want to have the text on your `JLabel` updated? when pressing a button, or when writing text into your `JTextField`? I think you will need to use a Listener.

Comment: One question, everytime i initialize the login panel, do i have to write it the same way? i hae this in my processedpanel  Login_JPanel              LoginJP              = new Login_JPanel ();
 do i write this in every class i need to use it?

Comment: yeahh i have a listener in my processedpanel   else
    if ( e.getSource() == LoginJP.playerregistrationJB )
   {
        
    LoginJP.setVisible(false);
    
    add(PlayerRegistrationJP);
    PlayerRegistrationJP.setVisible(true);
    
   
   }

Comment: you don't have to write it in every class you use `PlayerRegistration_JPanel` but you need the instance of `Login_JPanel`

Comment: one question too: where are the panels? on the same frame? and how many instance are existing?

Comment: all of my panels are on one frame

Comment: maybe it would be more simple (maybe somebody corrects me) to put the 2 Panels in the same class. Then you can put a Listener (keylistener) to the JTextField. so on every Keyevent you can set the text of the JLable